# Using Custom Sort with Track Scores set to True is still showing score as null

Tags: react-native, elasticsearch

So I'm setting a default query in my React Native app. Essentially I'm trying to set a sortOrder based on the elementOrder values. My partner used this same piece of code in his web app and it works for him. It doesn't seem to work on my end. The score exists if I remove the custom sort, which is normal due to what I've read in the docs.  When I'm using a custom sort, then I should add `track_scores: true`. My score is still coming up as null.

I am not sure how to debug this situation. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks! Here's my code and let me know if you need to see anything. Unfortunately I don't have access to Kibana. I'm just console logging the list item and it's properties.

```js
const defaultQueryConfig = {
  track_scores: true,
  sort: {
    _script: {
      type: 'number',
      script: {
        lang: 'painless',
        source: `
            int sortOrder = 0;
            if (doc['elementOrder'].value == 1) {sortOrder =  3}
            else if (doc['elementOrder'].value == 3) {sortOrder =  2}
            else if (doc['elementOrder'].value == 2) {sortOrder =  1} 
            sortOrder; 
          `,
      },
      order: 'desc',
    },
  },
  query: {
    function_score: {
      query: {
        match_all: {},
      },
      functions: [
        {
          filter: {
            match: {
              categoryType: 'earth',
            },
          },
          weight: 100,
        },
        {
          filter: {
            match: {
              categoryType: 'water',
            },
          },
          weight: 90,
        },
        {
          filter: {
            match: {
              categoryType: 'fire',
            },
          },
          weight: 80,
        },
        {
          filter: {
            match: {
              thingExists: false,
            },
          },
          weight: 2,
        },
      ],
      score_mode: 'multiply',
    },
  },
};
```